# DynamoDB joins with multiple tables

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am developing ERP system. I am using AWS lambda(Node) with Dynamo DB. I am new in dynamo. **We are using multiple tables**.

My one small use case is like this,
I have one company table in which company's address will be store. In that address fields there is city, state, country fields which will have primary key of master tables(City, state, country).

So I need to fetch city,state and country also when i fetch company details in **single query**. Also filter, sorting should be done from master table.

So can anyone help me with this that there is any way to implement this? And if possible also provide some node js query code for reference.

If possible provide some official doc so I can review that.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yqfmXiZTlM

Comment: You are trying to apply concepts of relational databases to a NoSQL database. You are definitely going to have huge amounts of pain if you don't know what you are doing. Maybe have a look at [AWS Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/). It is a serverless relational database. You might be better served with that.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is a fantastic technology.  However, it is completely different than SQL databases.  As such, you'll need to approach the entire process differently than you would with a SQL database.

Entire books have been written on the subject, so I won't try to cover all the differences here.  However, I'll pass along a few pointers to get you in the right direction.

- Single table design is considered a best practice in DynamoDB.  Having multiple tables isn't necessarily an anti-pattern, but spend some time investigating *why* this is the case.  A good place to start: DynamoDB does not have a SQL join operation!
- [The DynamoDB Book](https://www.dynamodbbook.com/) is the best book on this topic, hands down.  Spending just a few hours reading this book will drastically reduce the learning curve.
- Watch AWS Re:Invent talks on DynamoDB.  [This talk from 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE&ab_channel=AWSEvents) is a great place to start. (This talk is from Alex DeBrie, the author of the DynamoDB Book).
- The rules of SQL databases do not apply when working with NoSQL databases.  In other words, forget everything you know about SQL databases when working with NoSQL.  It's a paradigm shift, and I find it best to set aside any preconceived notions about databases and approach the topic with an open mind.  Easier said than done, but it's my advice anyway :)
- DynamoDB requires that you build your data model to match the use cases of your application, aka your application "access patterns".  Throwing your data into DynamoDB before thinking about how you need to access the data is the wrong approach.  Instead, ask yourself "what are all the ways my application needs to get data?" and design your data model accordingly.

NoSQL data modeling has a steep learning curve, but it's *awesome* when you get it right!  Good luck!